# Getter in Vues not updating

Tags: vuex

I have a module in my VUex state

```
mutations: {
    appendTasks(state, tasks) {
    tasks.forEach((task) => {
        state.tasks[task.id] = task;
    });
    },
},
state: {
    tasks: {},
},
getters: {
    getTasks(state) {
    return Object.values(state.tasks);
    },
    getTasksCount(state) {
    return Object.keys(state.tasks).length;
    },
},
```

I want to store `tasks` as dictionary because I need to access them by id. Also I need a method to get a list if tasks. But `getTasks` doesn't work for me. And `getTasks` returns an empty Array Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation of my problem and how to solve it

Just use `Vue.set()`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects